# Image isn't being transparent

Tags: c#

so I'm working on this program, and for some reason pink wont go transparent, here's my code:

```
if (chatIcons.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255) || chatIcons.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255))
{
chatIcons.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

0, 255, 255 is the cyan (works)
255, 0, 255 is the pink (doesn't work)
Why is that? the code works on one bit but not the other.

Oh and here's my image:
[image]

Comment: Ideally it should work ...have you checked if it's exact 0, 255, 255?

Comment: maybe try `new Color(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: Also 255, 0, 255 is the pink and 0, 255, 255 is the cyan.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, updated post now. Oh and Rameez, I have checked countless amounts of times.

Comment: are you sure that the image as (255,0,255)?...if its 255,1,255 it will not work.

Comment: Yeah I'm 100% sure the RGB values are 100% correct, I've checked it over and over and over.

Comment: I believe it's actually *magenta* not pink.

Comment: is chat icons bitmap?

Comment: @BobbyDigital It doesn't matter, I know it's magenta but that word isn't used anywhere, it's still the same RGB values

Comment: The people in the namesake town of Magenta Italy will be sad to hear that

Comment: It was informational. Magenta *is* used. I don't know where you would get that idea. Perhaps you're speaking in a very limited context. Printer cartridges, drafting standards (i.e.; AutoDesk family), and [Photoshop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS705A7236-E699-4730-A893-59B0C3F1B756a.html) still use magenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its bitmap(and if your image supports Alpha) you can try this:

```
chatIcons = ChangeColor(chatIcons,(byte)255,(byte)0,(byte)255);

public static Bitmap ChangeColor(Bitmap sourceBitmap, byte blue, byte green, byte red)
{
       BitmapData sourceData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                    sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height),
                                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

       byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];

       Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length);

       sourceBitmap.UnlockBits(sourceData);

       for (int k = 0; k + 4 < pixelBuffer.Length; k += 4)
       {
           if (pixelBuffer[k] == blue && pixelBuffer[k + 1] == green && pixelBuffer[k + 2] == red)
           {
                pixelBuffer[k] = 0;
                pixelBuffer[k + 1] = 0;
                pixelBuffer[k + 2] = 0;
                pixelBuffer[k + 3] = 0;
           }
        }

        Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height);

        BitmapData resultData = resultBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                    resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height),
                                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

         Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, pixelBuffer.Length);
            resultBitmap.UnlockBits(resultData);

         return resultBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that worked well, except there is 1 magenta pixel in the bottom right.

Comment: It could be a problem with the image, as I used the same code to make the aqua transparent and it worked fine, I really appreciate this thank you.

Comment: I added your code, and it worked good, but there was a single magenta pixel in the bottom right that wont go :s

Comment: ok i dont know why with that image it does that,with all images works great but with yours i tried and it leaves the last pixel magenta,maybe some kind o shading in the borders,but in the for loop where its k + 4 < pixelbuffer change to <=.just for this because with rest should work 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the image with Axialis and was presented with this result (no modifications, but zoomed for capture)...

[image: zoomed]

So this would lead to the conclusion that the encoding inside the image is such that the pink pixels are interpreted as transparent by SOME decoders and not others.  Photoshop decoded and presented the image as expected.  You may need to open and save it under Photoshop to 'override' whatever encoding is affecting the pink pixels.

Also about your code for colour detection.  A very deep zoom with Photoshop revealed lots of artefacts to the extent that an exact detection method such as yours is likely to fail in about 10 - 20 % of the pixels.  You might consider a detection method along the lines of 'IsNearlyPink'

Photoshop zoom below...

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand, in GIMP it's solid pink :S

Comment: I just downloaded Axialis and opened the image and it's still pink. EDIT: Oh wait I see it now.

Comment: @bloodless2010, what did you see?  Can you amend your question?

Comment: I opened the image in Axialis, I added the magenta colouring, RGB 255 0 255, and saved it, but it still wont work :/ Sorry I am new to this site.

Comment: @bloodless2010, welcome to SO!  I suggest taking these comments we've exchanged and editing your original question so that people will know what you have tried.  SO culture really appreciates advance knowledge of what people have tried so far.  Go to your question and click 'edit' and etc etc.  It's fun!

Comment: but I don't quite know what is going on ATM, I can't try anything because everything is always pink

Answer (score 0):

The PixelFormat of your Bitmap-Object have to support the Alpha-Channel, like PixelFormats.Bgra32

Comment: How would I make it support Alpha-Channel?